# Is there a curated repository for DJango based website templates?

Tags: python, django

Where can I find a list of (preferably curated) DJango based, simple-website, templates (or equivalent, prewritten, boilerplate DJango code and layout)?

**Context**

I'm considering a project which requires me to deploy a large number of (fairly simple) personal/vanity websites. They are simple enough that, most likely, I should be able to deploy them as Wordpress based websites, using a few existing templates.

However, I'm not a fan of Wordpress, and I'd like to see if I can get roughly the same result by working with Python/DJango.

Comment: [A similar question][1] has been asked, and may have the information you're looking for


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550949/where-are-the-best-lists-of-existing-django-apps

Comment: @Reinbach that questions is useful to me, but not exactly what I am looking for; I'm lazy enough to look for boilerplate which includes everything I'd need for deploying simple, basic sites, removing even the simple steps of requiring that I find the right application(s) for my needs and then do a basic install for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) has a lot of pre-baked code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no similar "themes" for Django like you'd find for Wordpress. Wordpress is a CMS -- a full application -- whereas Django is a *framework* -- i.e., you could use it to build a Wordpress, but it is not a Wordpress. You could start off with a pure HTML/CSS template and use that to build in functionality, but you won't find anything Django-specific, because it would inherently depend on what you build.

Comment: It seems you're answering a question different from the one I intended to ask (I'm not sure how to phrase the question to remove the suggestion that the difference between a framework and a CMS system might be relevant). I'm looking for curated, boiler plate code, including simple layouts, removing much of the trudging involved in building the common components of simple websites; it seems reasonable to expect that I might find that, for a framework as popular and well supported as Django